# Is there a way to get all fetched ids from a PHP while loop?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I want to know if I can get all fetched ids from a PHP while loop to use them in a jQuery for a flip effect?

```
while ($fetch_locomotion = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_locomotion))
{
    $id = $fetch_locomotion['id'];

    echo 
    '<a href="index.php?price='.$hash.'" style="text-decoration: none;" id="object_a_jquery">
        <div id="'.$id.'" style="perspective:1000px;height:100%;width:13%;display:inline-table;">
            <div class="front">
                <div id="object_list_price_bg" style="background-image:url(images/bg_price_f.png);"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="back">
                <div id="object_list_price_bg_b" style="background-image:url(images/bg_price.png);"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>';
}


<script>$(<?php echo $id;?>).flip();</script>
```

Comment: I think you'll get this if you think through the process one step at a time. Remember that PHP and JavaScript (jQuery) are executed at different times. PHP outputs a file, the file is sent to the browser, the browser reads the file and executes any JavaScript in it. So you are using PHP to write JavaScript, just like you use PHP to write HTML.

Comment: Hey Josef, thanks for your answer. I tried to understand your answer but i cant follow you.. Do you mean i have to write an own js file for it? I also tried to increment the whole id in jquery with variable counter. And also to inplement the <script> inside the while loop. But i dont get it how it will work. Im new in js so i cant understand much.

Comment: Hi, I see that SpenceLogan has already elaborated on this with code examples. But what you seemed to be missing was an understanding that PHP is executed on the server and does not understand the HTML and JS it is producing. JavaScript, on the other hand, is run in the browser and knows nothing about the PHP that generated it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can dump them into an array and use them at a later time.

```
// do this before entering the loop so it isn't overwritten
$ids = [];
// Do this part inside of the while loop
$ids[] = $fetch_locomotion ['id'];

?>

/* do this part in the html section you wish to execute the javascript code */
<script>
jQuery(function ($) {
    <?php foreach ($ids as $id): ?>
        <?php echo "$('#". $id . "').flip();\n"; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
});
</script>
```

Edited for your exact code:

```
$ids = [];
while ($fetch_locomotion = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_locomotion))
{

    $ids[] = $fetch_locomotion['id'];

    echo 
    '<a href="index.php?price='.$hash.'" style="text-decoration: none;" id="object_a_jquery">
        <div id="'. $fetch_locomotion ['id'] .'" style="perspective:1000px;height:100%;width:13%;display:inline-table;">
            <div class="front">
                <div id="object_list_price_bg" style="background-image:url(images/bg_price_f.png);"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="back">
                <div id="object_list_price_bg_b" style="background-image:url(images/bg_price.png);"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>';
}


<script>
jQuery(function ($) {
    <?php foreach ($ids as $id): ?>
        <?php echo "$('#". $id . "').flip();\n"; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
});
</script>
```

Comment: Hey, i tried to implement this code. But it didn't work for me. Do i have to keep my single id fetch or do i have to replace this with the array? And should the variable '$ids[]' store all ids from the while at the end (outside of the while)? So if i click one of my id in a class it should do the flip effect? Hope you can understand me

Comment: You'd use either $ids or $fetch_locomotion ['id'] in place of $id in the code you already have. The first block needs to be inside of the while loop so you can get all of the id's from your query. The second block will print one flip statement for each id in the array.

Comment: `$ids = [];` shouldn't be inside the loop.

Comment: I just edited my answer (yes $ids should be outside of the loop). Hopefully that's helpful. Will double check.

Comment: Well.. this worked for me. Thanks for your help. Didn't knew that you can use ids after a loop

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest adding a class attribute and querying on it (instead of each ID separately).

Also, using the alternative PHP syntax would be cleaner in this context.

This becomes:

```
<?php while ($fetch_locomotion = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_locomotion)): ?>
  <a href="index.php?price=<?= $hash ?>" style="text-decoration: none;" id="object_a_jquery_<?= $id ?>">
    <div id="<?= $fetch_locomotion['id'] ?>" class="js-flipMe" style="perspective:1000px;height:100%;width:13%;display:inline-table;">
      <div class="front">
        <div id="object_list_price_bg" style="background-image:url(images/bg_price_f.png);"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="back">
        <div id="object_list_price_bg_b" style="background-image:url(images/bg_price.png);"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
<?php endwhile ?>

<script>
  jQuery(function ($) {
    $('.js-flipMe').flip();
  });
</script>
```

Note that I also changed your `<a>`'s `id` attribute to be unique, as it should be.